# Bootstrap Control Layout Offset Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngsye3pv/1/) which is a cut down sample of a page I am working on utilising bootstrap for the styling.

**NOTE: When viewing the fiddle, make sure the Result pane is wide enough to have the first 3 controls on a single row!**

The issue that I have is that the 'Free Text Search' row of controls seem to be offset to the right more than I would like. I want the 'Free Text Search' label to be directly under the 'Store Number' label and the same width. Along with that I wand the corresponding input to start at the beginning of the 'Store Number' input and finish at the end of the 'Parent Category' select.

I can't quite see where I have gone wrong with the bootstrap classes.

Here is my html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <h3 style="padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">A pointless title</h3>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="storeNumber" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Store Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="storeNumber" class="form-control" type="text"
                 name="storeNumber" placeholder="Store Number" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="actionedTo" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Actioned To</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select id="actionedTo" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="parentCategory" 
             class="col-sm-4 control-label">Parent Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select id="parentCategory" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="freeTextSearch" 
             class="col-sm-2 control-label">Free Text Search</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="freeTextSearch" class="form-control" type="text"
                 name="requestNumber" placeholder="Free Text Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general structure is counter to your classes. You're structuring for your inputs to position inline but you're using [form-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) and you're nesting `columns`.

You don't need any of that markup for this. Just use the `form-group` class and `columns`.

See working Snippet.

*The CSS I've added isn't needed to make everything work but I believe it looks better on larger viewports with it.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .lg-group {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  h3.form-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3 Header</a>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3 class="form-title">A Pointless Title</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="storeNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Store Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input id="storeNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name="storeNumber" placeholder="Store Number" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="actionedTo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actioned To</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select id="actionedTo" class="form-control" name="actionedTo"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="parentCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parent Category</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select id="parentCategory" class="form-control" name="parentCategory"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group lg-group">
      <label for="requestNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Free Text Search</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="freeTextSearch" class="form-control" type="text" name="requestNumber" placeholder="Free Text Search" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Alternative Layout for Multiple Controls

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .lg-group {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  h3.form-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3 Header</a>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3 class="form-title">A Pointless Title</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="myForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="lg-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="storeNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Store Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input id="storeNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name="storeNumber" placeholder="Store Number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="actionedTo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actioned To</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select id="actionedTo" class="form-control" name="actionedTo"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="parentCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parent Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select id="parentCategory" class="form-control" name="parentCategory"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="lg-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="storeNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Store Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input id="storeNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name="storeNumber" placeholder="Store Number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="actionedTo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Actioned To</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select id="actionedTo" class="form-control" name="actionedTo"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="parentCategory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parent Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select id="parentCategory" class="form-control" name="parentCategory"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group lg-group">
          <label for="requestNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Free Text Search</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="freeTextSearch" class="form-control" type="text" name="requestNumber" placeholder="Free Text Search" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! With a bit of tweaking that worked well for my solution apart from in one way. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1zdpsnug/) is a fiddle showing the same as before but with 2 rows of 3 controls (please ignore the fact it is 100% copy and pasted!), but I was under the impression that the rows of controls should have a gap between them by the use of the `form-horizontal` class. Do I have to do this manually now?

Comment: See the updated answer with an alternative layout for multiple rows of controls. This can probably be refactored but it should help get you to the desired results.

Comment: Perfection! Thanks very much!